# localisation in iOS application in two language

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have localized my iOS application in French and English now

[image]

I want to add German language in my project.
For `NSlocalized` string I have created a `localizable` file for French, how can I create another `localizable` file for German languages,i am using this code for localizing strings

```
NSLocalizedString("ReJoin Now", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
```

Comment: Similar to localizable file for French, create similar for german.. whats new here?

Comment: What is the question ? If you have done this for french, just repeat the steps but make it german ?

Comment: please check my video for localisation you can change multiple language using this approach :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9NV81z5ojo